# App to practice investing money?

Tags: windows, gratis, web-apps, educational, finance

I'm looking for some sort of practice software or game where I would be given some (fictional) money and I would use that money to invest in shares or stocks or something and see how much money I could make after certain periods of time, or ongoing.

It would be great if it had "multiplayer" component i.e. you could start at the same time as some friends and see who makes the most money via a leaderboard.

I have Windows and the app must be free. While it's okay if the app only has one type of investment option available, if it has more that will be a real plus. The app must be as realistic as possible as I want to get a bit of practice (and fun) before attempting to do it with real money.

Comment: TradeHero is an iPhone app.  I think there are vanilla financial tools that provide this as well except without limit on the fake money.

Comment: Since there is web-app in the tag, I'm guessing including a web game is fine? I'm suggesting looking towards Wiki's page on [Stock market simulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_market_simulator). I have tried some of them, and I prefer Investopedia as it is bareboned. I haven't tried any of them using a smartphone since I haven't played on Investopedia for a long time, but since most pages work fine with Firfox's request desktop mode, I'm guessing most of these web games will do just fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options:

### 1. Investopedia

This is a more simple and user friendly option that is played through your web browser.

You can choose to play with other real people worldwide or just by yourself. You can also create your own games and play with your friends.

You can find more about Investopedia here: [Link to site](https://www.investopedia.com/simulator/)

[image: investopedia image]

**NOTE:**
This second option is probably not the way you want to go. It is much more difficult and does not just work right out of the box. In addition it does not have the online, multilayer functionality that Investopedia has.

### 2. Ninja Trader

This is a more difficult and advanced piece of software.

I would only recommend this if you know what your doing and have lots of time to spend learning the ins and out of this program.

More about Ninja Trader can be found here: [Link to site](https://ninjatrader.com)

[image: ninja trader]

Hope this helps!